# Trying to add a button to a webpage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a button to my webpage using JavaScript but the console is giving me an error saying:

> scripts.js:35 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.

```js
// 7: Create a <button> element, and set its text to 'Delete'
// Add the <button> inside the '.extra' <div>
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = "Delete";
const buttonPlace = document.getElementsByClassName('.extra')[0];
document.appendChild(button);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>Practice Manipulating the DOM</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1></h1>
    <p class="desc"></p>
    <ul>
      <li><input> Play music</li>
      <li><input> Swim</li>
      <li><input> Bike ride</li>
      <li><input> Code</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="extra">
      <p>This is extra content you need to delete.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any idea on what's going on? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `button.innerHTML` -> `button.textContent`? Also, you're inserting into `html` not `body`... try using `document.body.appendChild` instead.

Comment: There should not be a dot in the class name passed to `getElementsByClassName()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only element you can put on the document is `<html>` (which is there by default).

If you want to add a `<button>` to the page, then you need to add it somewhere else (and that should be as a descendant of the `<body>` element).

> ```
> const buttonPlace = document.getElementsByClassName('.extra')[0];
> ```

The above looks like a the spot you want to put the button, but you need to append it there and not to the `document` object.

```
buttonPlace.appendChild(button);
```

---

Note that in CSS, the `.` indicates a start of a class selector. Your class name does not start with a `.` character. You'll need to correct that at the point you call `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @Jackson — That what I said.

Comment: @Jackson – Yes, that's what I said.